# Javascript Events Not Bubbling Up When Using Text Box Watermark

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, watermark

I'm trying to implement a simple watermark on a text box that disappears when the text box gains focus.  I found this jQuery plugin that appeared to work great:

http://remysharp.com/2007/01/25/jquery-tutorial-text-box-hints/

The watermark worked just as advertised with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/_jQuery/_Library/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/_jQuery/_plugs/_hint/jquery.hint.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[title!=]").hint();
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" title="Blah" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, when adding an alert to the click event of the table, I found that the event doesn't bubble up when you click on the portion of the text box that has text.  However it bubbles up just fine when you click on the part of the text box without text.  Here is the jQuery code that I used to create the alert:

```
        $("table").click(function() {
            alert("blah");
        });
```

Does anybody have any idea why the event doesn't bubble up when part of the text box is clicked, but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody have any idea why the event doesn't bubble up when part of the text box is clicked

It seems to be a Firefox-specific bug affecting both text inputs and textareas. You can reproduce it with just a few lines of code, it's not jQuery-related or to do with the plugin:

```
<form onclick="alert('hello')">
    <input type="text" value="hello!" onfocus="this.value=''">
</form>
```

(Although I think the plugin does have some fairly significant problems. It forgets to use ‘var’ on local variables, letting them leak out to global scope. This makes multiple ‘.blur’ elements on the same page fail. Plus ‘empty’ values will still be submitted to the form as the title string, and you can't distinguish ‘real’ values typed by the user that match the title string.)

The event only fails to bubble when the input's value is *changed in the focus event*. Speculatively, my guess is that Firefox is internally recognising that the click() occurred on text inside the input, and expecting to bubble that event up each of the text's ancestors. But when the click event on the immediate parent causes onfocus to fire, that function is removing the text from its parent. Now there's nothing for the click event to have occurred on, no parent chain to bubble through.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The bug is also in both Safari and Chrome, but that's an interesting theory. I'll see if I can find a way around it.

Comment: Hmm, you're right! Interesting, there aren't many cases where IE gets it right but both Mozilla and Webkit fail! FWIW no such bug on Opera.

Comment: Haha, I was thinking the same thing. I was able to get it work by putting a 150 millisecond delay before removing the text, this allowed the bubbling up to occur before the text is removed.  Not exactly elegant, but it works. If you can think of a more elegant work around, please let me know.

Comment: As a side note, some of your comments on the plugin are inaccurate. While it's impossible to distinguish between real values and the title, I'm going to validate for that. All local variables are made local by var and the .blur in jQuery adds to, instead of overriding, so it's not a problem either.

Comment: Ah, you're right, those are commas in a var statement, not separate semicolon-separated statements. Wow, that's... questionable. :-)